# Integration of Cypress with burp

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cucumberjs

I want to set proxy for my Cypress test cases

I was using **set HTTP_PROXY=http://my-company-proxy.com** so that my burp sitemap get populated with the urls of my app.

I have tried set HTTP_PROXY=http://my-company-proxy.com on cmd but its not setting the proxy.

Can anyone suggest?

Note: I am using cypress-cucumber framework and cypress version is 3.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

npm config set http-proxy http://my-company-proxy.com

npm config set proxy http://my-company-proxy.com